# Using gosu with kubernetes runAsUser security context?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a base container that has an `ENTRYPOINT` that runs as root:

Base container Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.io/opensuse/leap:latest

# Add scripts to be executed during startup
COPY startup /startup
ADD https://example.com/install-ca-cert.sh /startup/startup.d/install-ca-cert-base.sh
RUN chmod +x /startup/* /startup/startup.d/*

# Add Tini
ENV TINI_VERSION v0.18.0
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /tini
RUN chmod +x /tini
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "/startup/startup.sh"]
```

And a derived container that uses [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) to perform a root step down after the startup scripts have been run as root:

Derived container Dockerfile:

```
ADD ./gosu-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/gosu-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/gosu-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["whoami"]
```

gosu-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# Call original entrypoint (as root)
/tini -s /startup/startup.sh

# If GOSU_USER environment variable is set, execute the specified command as that user
if [ -n "$GOSU_USER" ]; then
    useradd --shell /bin/bash --system --user-group --create-home @GOSU_USER
    exec /usr/local/bin/gosu $GOSU_USER "$@"
else
    # else GOSU_USER environment variable is not set, execute the specified command as the default (root) user
    exec "$@"
fi
```

This all works fine, by setting the `GOSU_USER` env var and running the container, the startup scripts are executed as root, and the `CMD` is executed as `GOSU_USER`:

```
export GOSU_USER=jim
docker run my-derived-container
# outputs "jim"
...
unset GOSU_USER
docker run my-derived-container
# outputs root
```

However, I am trying to determine if the above approach (maybe modified) is able to work with the Kubernetes [securityContext](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) `runAsUser` and `runAsGroup` directives?

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsGroup: 3000
    fsGroup: 2000
```

I think these directives are turned into the containerd equivalent of `docker run --user=xxx:yyy`, so as such, they wouldn't work, since this:

```
docker run --user $(id -u):$(id -g) my-derived-container
```

results in a permissions error due to the startup scripts not being run as root anymore.

I have seen examples of `entrypoint.sh` scripts that allow the container to be started with the `--user` flag, but not sure if thats something I can use or not, i.e. even if the `--user` flag is provided, I still need the startup scripts to run as root:

https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/master/5.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L11

```
# allow the container to be started with `--user`
if [ "$1" = 'redis-server' -a "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
    find . \! -user redis -exec chown redis '{}' +
    exec gosu redis "$0" "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

Update: Looking again at the above redis example, I'm not sure if this does allow the container to be started with `--user` as it states, looking at the Dockerfile, `redis-server` is the `CMD` passed to the script ($1):

https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/master/5.0/Dockerfile#L118

```
CMD ["redis-server"]
```

and the `redis` user is just hardcoded in the above `docker-entrypoint.sh`:

Comment: short answer: no  / your last test is correct. To use gosu, you'ld need `securityContext.privileged: true`, `securityContext.runAsUser: 0`, and maybe a PodSecurityPolicy + RBAC granting your ServiceAccount with permissions starting privileged containers. Usually better to go with stuff like nsswrapper, if passwd/group entries are actually required.